# "obstacle to developing '" vs "obstacle in developing"?

Tags: prepositions

Which proposition are used after obstacle? I have seen both "in" and "to". what are the difference between them? for example, what is the difference between the following sentences/
There is an obstacle in developing .....
or
There is an obstacle to  developing ......

Answer (score 3):

An obstacle in developing implies that the development is in progress. At least one part of the development is halted due to an obstacle.

An obstacle to developing suggests that development as a whole cannot commence because of an obstacle.